# proc gplot Spaghetti Plot on more than 255 subjects

Tags: graph, sas

Hi I have a question when trying to make a spaghetti plot. I don't want each subject to have different symbols or colors. I just need them to each have a black segmented line. I have been able to do it successfully with fewer subjects, by just create the same symbol statement for everyone and use gplot, but when I do it with more than 255 subjects, SAS complains that I can't have more than 255 symbols. Is there a way to do this?

```
data _null_; 
set ptdata&trtn. end=eof; 
retain patcount 0; 
by usubjid;
if first.usubjid then patcount+1; 
if last.usubjid then lastgfr='Y'; 
   call symput('sym'||trim(left(patcount)), 
   'symbol'||trim(left(patcount)) 
   || ' '|| 'c=black'|| ' '||'v=Dot'||' ' 
   || 'i=join'|| ' ' || 'line=1' || 'width=1' ||';');
if eof then call symput('total',patcount); 
run;

%macro symbol;
%do j=1 %to &total; 
&&sym&j 
%end; 
%mend symbol;

%symbol

proc gplot data = ptdata&trtn. ;
  plot change_since_bl*FUPTIME=usubjid /haxis=axis3 vaxis=axis4 href=0 nolegend;
  format change_since_bl 8. ;*/
run ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `PROC SGPLOT`, it is not limited to 255 like GPLOT and it is easier to use.

Try this:

```
data test;
do person=1 to 256;
    value = 100;
    do time=0 to 10;
        value = value + rannor(1);
        output;
    end;
end;
run;

proc sgplot data=test noautolegend;
series x=time y=value / group=person lineattrs=(color=black pattern=dash) ;
run;
```

I think this is what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: I tried sgplot, but for some reason it keeps giving me the following error. Not sure if it's because I"m using gslide?
    ERROR: Cannot write image to SGPlot1.png. Please ensure that proper disk permissions are set.

Comment: That's a problem with permissions on the file system.  Look at where you are trying to write and ask your systems admin where you should be outputting the image file.  Control that through the `ODS` statement.

Comment: But I'm using the same gframe as before, and didn't have a problem. Somehow I feel like the sgplot is not getting plugged into greplay statement or something like that.

Comment: I see.  I don't have much experience with GREPLAY.  I would ask that as a separate question and get someone that knows it better.

Comment: Thank you for your help!